# Retrieving opencv error (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, opencv, opencv3.0

I have the following code where I am sending continuous data from the streamer to the viewer. I am retrieving error in cv function resize

Streamer.py

```
footage_socket.connect('tcp://localhost:8080')
videoFile = "D:/sample.mp4"
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(videoFile)
while True:
  grabbed, frame = camera.read()
  try:
      frame = cv2.resize( frame, (224, 224) ).astype( "float32" )
 except cv2.error:
      break
  image= img_to_array(frame)
  image=image.reshape((1,image.shape[0],image.shape[1],image.shape[2]))
  image=preprocess_input(image)
  preds=model.predict(image)
  footage_socket.send(preds)
footage_socket.close()
```

Viewer.py

```
context = zmq.Context()
footage_socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
footage_socket.bind('tcp://*:8080')
footage_socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, np.unicode(''))
while True:
    frame = footage_socket.recv()
    img = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(base64.b64decode(frame),dtype = np.uint8),1)
    frame = cv2.resize( img, (224, 224) )
    image = img_to_array( frame )
    image = image.reshape( (1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[2]) )
    image = preprocess_input( image )
    predictions = m1.predict(img)
 footage_socket.close()
```

I am retrieving the below error

```
frame = cv2.resize( img, (224, 224) )
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4045: error: 
(-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'
```

Help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Most probably `footage_socket.recv()` returns null

Comment: thanks much appreciated I will have a look at this @Ahx

Comment: I am able to retrieve data its not empty @Ahx

Comment: Then did you display the image `cv2.imshow("img", img); cv2.waitKey(0) `?

Comment: I don't need to display the image, but I will check and see this. I just need to send the prediction results once the image is converted into frames @Ahx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing the code from recv_string() to recv_pyobj() and from send() to send_pyobj() and the code works perfectly fine. Thanks